Switching to Craft from Bolt - yii or symfony or laravel or what?
My company has several large websites running on BoltCMS.  It seems like Bolt is no longer undergoing active development.  I was just installing and fiddling around with yii to familiarize myself with it when I saw this post here suggesting that yii isn't going to be around for the next version of Craft.
Is there any more news on that situation?  There is still a part of one of our websites running on symfony1.0, so we've got a head start if that turns out to be your choice :)

Craft 6 will begin the transition to Laravel from what I understand. This has been discussed here and there in talks, Discord comments, etc. (Craft 5 is the current version).
Perhaps the most official is this: https://www.craftcms.com/blog/change-of-plans#:~:text=and%20kick%20off%20our%20transition%20to%20Laravel.
I think Brandon (CEO) may have covered it in his recent Craft Dot One video, but it's not up currently. It will be here presumably: https://craftcms.com/events/dot-one-toronto-2024/sessions/state-of-craft-2024
Anyway - the underlying framework matters very little to most developers. Plugin developers are the ones who will have to make the most changes, but the Craft team has said they plan to implement polyfills along the way to make it easier.
Highly recommend Craft CMS - so straightforward and easy to extend. It really gets the basics right and is fairly unopinionated from there.
